# Changing Theorem environment from Italicized to Slanted

Tags: fonts

I want to change the font in the Theorem environment from the default italicized text to slanted text because the latter is sharp, whereas the former is sort of blurry. Could anyone please help me with this?

Edit : incomplete MWE:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{uhmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{math dots} %??
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
 \begin{thm}  
 \end{thm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small code of what you've tried?

Comment: Please identify the document package and theorem class you are using.  (The description of italic as "blurry" raises the question whether there is also a problem with the rendering in print or on screen, or if the shape is a personal reaction.  Some people *do* prefer slanted type for theorems, even though it defies tradition, as it makes the distinction between text and math more obvious.)

Comment: I use \documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{uhmath}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{math dots}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

I use \begin{thm}   \end{thm}

Comment: It is definitely a personal reaction; I find italics difficult to read. Maybe instead of "blurry," I should have said that I find italicized text sort of "wobbly."

Comment: Could you please edit that preamble into your answer with readable formatting? Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be using `amsthm` indirectly through another package. A lot of your `\usepackage` commands are redundant. If so, you’d want to define a  `\newtheoremstyle` that sets the body font to a slanted font. That’s the `{sl}` shape rather than `{it}`, so you’d normally select it with `\slshape`.

Comment: I know that I can change the font manually by just writing /sl at the beginning of the Theorem's statement. But I'd like to do it automatically.

Comment: @Davislor I have copied the code posted in comment into the OP, but it is still not compilable. For Mishel Skenderi : By the way the command for slanted is not \sl but \slshape.

Comment: @Davislor I agree but i felt that it was not clear for Mishel, as he used sl  command in his reply.

Comment: @Jhor Ah, pardon. That looked like a reply to me. I’ll clean up.

Comment: The way to do it automatically is to define a `\newtheoremstyle` that selects it as a feature of the theorem font.

Comment: The `psamsfonts` option has been obsolete for several years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the definition of `\th@plain`. I took the occasion for adding some comments to your code.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart} % psamsfonts is obsolete

%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,arc,cmtip]{xy} % add cmtip to get decent arrow tips
%\usepackage{enumerate} % incompatible with enumitem
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{uhmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{latexsym} % not needed with amssymb
\usepackage{mathdots} % if you need it, but no space
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\th@plain{\slshape}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is slanted.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the due respect, I heartily disagree with Knuth about slanted type, which I find ugly and difficult to distinguish from upright type.

In order to get also “Proof” in slanted type, you need to patch `\proof`. There has been debate on AMS providing a hook for this, but it's not yet available.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart} % psamsfonts is obsolete

%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,arc,cmtip]{xy} % add cmtip to get decent arrow tips
%\usepackage{enumerate} % incompatible with enumitem
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{uhmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{latexsym} % not needed with amssymb
\usepackage{mathdots} % if you need it, but no space
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\th@plain{\slshape}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\slshape}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is slanted.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
The word ``Proof'' is slanted too.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does Knuth say about slanted type? Does he like it? I personally like it so much more than italicized type.

Comment: @MishelSkenderi Look in `plain.tex` for the definition of `\proclaim`.

Comment: Hi, I also wanted to ask about something related: How can I change the "Proof" in LaTeX to slanted type. As in, when one writes $\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}$, the "Proof." appears in italic type, not slanted type. I would like to get it in slanted type.

Comment: @MishelSkenderi Added.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{uhmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{math dots} %??
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{common}
    {6pt plus 5\p@ minus 2\p@}% above space (default)
    {6pt plus 5\p@ minus 2\p@}% below space
    {\slshape}% body
    {0em}% indent
    {\bfseries}% head
    {}% punct
    {.5em}% space
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }{#2}}%
 \thmnote{ {(#3)}}}% theorem head
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{common}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

 \begin{thm}  
This is for test
 \end{thm}

\end{document}
```

PS: Note that `slshape` is not advisable...